# Connection pool of Request object is smaller than optimal value (8) Trying to make a telegram bot and I cant seem to fix it

Tags: telegram-bot

import requests
import json
import os
import telegram
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from telegram import Bot
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
from telegram.utils.request import Request

request = Request(con_pool_size=10)
bot = telegram.Bot(token="bottoken", request=request)

Tried to use telegram.utils to fix my problem but its not working I have installed python telegram bot and its up to date